# Tauri window position 'Tray position not set'

Tags: javascript, rust, tauri

I'm using Tauri and Tauri Plugin Positioner. I've setup as per documentation:
main.rs:

```rust
fn main() {
    ...
    tauri::Builder::default()
    .plugin(tauri_plugin_positioner::init()) <- Initialised plugin
    .on_system_tray_event(|app, event| {
            tauri_plugin_positioner::on_tray_event(app, &event); <- Required for tray locations
            match event {
                SystemTrayEvent::LeftClick { position: _, size: _, .. } => {
                    ...
                },
                _ => {}
            }
        })
    ...
```

app.js from React frontend:

```js
import { move_window, Position } from 'tauri-plugin-positioner-api'
function App () {
    move_window(Position.TrayBottomRight)
    ...
```

I've also updated the cargo.toml file to include system-tray feature as that is apparently necessary:

```
tauri-plugin-positioner = { version = "1.0", features = ["system-tray"] }
```

I have tried it as 'Rust only' where the positioning is done through main.rs but it produced further errors.
The current error I am getting is:
`thread 'tokio-runtime-worker' panicked at 'Tray position not set'`
I have researched this but the documentation seems very limited. It seems to be mirrored from the Electron version, where they specify a traybounds argument in  `move_window(Position.TrayBottomRight, traybounds)`, but it errors as the argument is unexpected. My only thought is it is because of my `.on_system_tray_event` setup, but I can't figure out how to re-write it.
Can anyone point me in the right direction or spot what I've done wrong (fairly new to rust & tauri).

Answer (score 1):

You try to move your application window to the location of the system tray icon on startup before the user has even interacted with the tray. This makes little sense because the tray icon might not even be visible at that point and the user would not expect the application to open near the tray. To be clear: the system tray is the collection of icons on the bottom right of your screen.

Instead, you shoud move your window move logic to the event handler that opens your application window after the user has clicked your icon in the tray:

```rust
fn main() {
    ...
    tauri::Builder::default()
    .plugin(tauri_plugin_positioner::init())
    .on_system_tray_event(|app, event| {
            tauri_plugin_positioner::on_tray_event(app, &event);
            match event {
                SystemTrayEvent::LeftClick { position: _, size: _, .. } => {
                    // open the window here ...
                    // and only then move it:
                    app.move_window(Position.TrayBottomRight);`
                    // (although it would be better to immediately set the position while building the window)
                },
                _ => {}
            }
        })
    ...
```

If you have troubling opening the window when the user clicks the tray icon, you can consult: [I am trying to create a new window using Tauri 1.2, Rust, React, and Typescript. I am facing some issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76080859/i-am-trying-to-create-a-new-window-using-tauri-1-2-rust-react-and-typescript)

Comment: The issue I'm more having is with getting its initial position to open there and it not recognising ```TrayBottomRight```. E.g. It works with ```RightCentre``` on intial and when opened with right click, but wont work with ```TrayBottomRigh```.

Comment: I really think you should move the positioning logic inside the system tray handler and if that gives you an error you can try to fix that one.

Comment: I have the logic for re-opening the application on left click already: ```                SystemTrayEvent::LeftClick { position: _, size: _, .. } => {
                    let window = app.get_window("main").unwrap();
                    window.show().unwrap();
                    let _ = window.move_window(Position::RightCenter);
                },``` but the trayBottomRight still does not work.

Comment: Does it still give you the same error message or is it a different one now?

Comment: No still the same message.